# Caching Images - Bitmap not collected after different bitmap was loaded or ImageView's activity closed

Tags: android, image, caching, garbage-collection, out-of-memory

I am trying to implement something that is very similar to UrlImageViewHelper (https://github.com/koush/UrlImageViewHelper) where you can easily using a simple one line of code, load images from a url, and if the image was already downloaded it is loaded from the cache instead. The major difference is that I want the same effect but instead of downloading it from a url, I want to receive the images from my own server using my own client-server communication. Every image on my server can be uniquely identified by a string, and I use this as the id for the image.

My main idea was this: Use an LRU Cache to hold the images, but instead of holding the Bitmaps (that are very large) I want to hold the raw image data binary, so I can use the same image to build bitmaps of different sizes and qualities on demand depending on the specific situation.

This is my implementation so far:

```
    public class ImageHandler {

    private static class BitmapCache extends LruCache<String, byte[]>
    {
        public WigoBitmapCache(int maxSize) {
            super(maxSize);
        }

        @Override
        protected int sizeOf(String key, byte[] value) {
            return value.length;
        }

    }

    private static class ImageHandlerThread extends Thread
    {

            /* THIS THREAD WILL DECODE THE IMAGE AND SET THE BITMAP TO THE IMAGEVIEW IN THE BACKGROUND */   
                Activity activity;
        ImageView imageView;
        byte[] imageBytes;

        public ImageHandlerThread(Activity activity, ImageView imageView, byte[] imageBytes)
        {
            this.activity=activity;
            this.imageView=imageView;
            this.imageBytes=imageBytes;
        }

        public void run() {

            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.length, o);
            int factor1=o.outHeight/height;
            int factor2=o.outWidth/width;
                        /* height and width are for now constant */
            o = null;
            o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            if (factor1>factor2)
                o.inSampleSize=factor1;
            else
                o.inSampleSize=factor2;
            Bitmap bit = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.length,o);
            setBitmap(bit);
            bit = null;

        }


        private void setBitmap(final Bitmap bit) {
            activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bit);

                }
            });     
        }

    }

    private static class QueueItem
    { /*USED TO HOLD INFO ABOUT THE IMAGE REQUEST UNTIL THE IMAGE GETS FROM THE SERVER */
        String imageName;
        Activity activity;
        ImageView imageView;

        public QueueItem(String imageName, Activity activity, ImageView imageView) 
        {
            this.imageName=imageName;
            this.activity = activity;
            this.imageView = imageView;
        }

    }

    private BitmapCache cache; // this cache holds the image binaries 
    private ArrayList<QueueItem> queue; // this queue holds the info about the request, until the server sends the image

    public ImageHandler(int maxSize)
    {
        cache=new BitmapCache(maxSize);
        queue = new ArrayList<QueueItem>();

    }

    public synchronized void setBitmap(Activity activity, ImageView imageView, String imageName)
    {
        byte[] imageBytes = cache.get(imageName);
        if (imageBytes==null)
        {
            QueueItem item = new QueueItem(imageName, activity, imageView);
            queue.add(item);    

            /* HERE IS THE CODE TO RETRIEVE THE IMAGE BINARY FROM MY SERVER, THIS CODE WORKS FINE, SO THERE IS NO REASON TO BOHER YOU WITH IT */

        }
        else
        {
            ImageHandlerThread thread = new ImageHandlerThread(activity, imageView, imageBytes);
            thread.start();
        }

    }

    public synchronized void insert (String imageName, byte[] imageBytes)
    {

        /* THIS METHOD IS THE CALLBACK THAT IS CALLED WHEN THE IMAGE BINARY IS RECEIVED FROM THE SERVER */

        cache.put(imageName, imageBytes);

        for (QueueItem item: queue)
        {
            if (item.imageName.equals(imageName))
            {
                ImageHandlerThread thread = new ImageHandlerThread(item.activity, item.imageView, imageBytes);
                thread.start();
                queue.remove(item);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, the main method here is setBitmap(), it gets the activity, the imageView that needs the bitmap, and the name of the image name. If the image is already in the cache, a new thread is started to decode the bytes into the proper size bitmap and set the bitmap to the imageView. If the image is not present in the cache, the request is put in a queue until the image is received, the image is retrieved from the server and then the same thread as before is started.

All this works absolutely fine, the problem is that when the imageView is set another bitmap for the image or even when the activity is destroyed, the bitmap is still resident in memory and is not collected by the GC.

At first I though that it is because I was keeping a reference to the activity, and that reference keeps the activity alive, but it seems not to be the case, my reference to an activity is very short lived, and once the image arrives from the server this reference is cleared.

I am running out of memory fast with this implementation, and I have no idea why or what to do to fix it. The bitmaps I create are not collected although I keep no references to them. Could this be an artifact of the way I decode the images? or do the threads keep references that are not collected properly? Anyone has any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I misunderstood the problem, what was happening is that the GC was not collecting the finished thread objects because I was running this in debug mode, and not in run mode. When I ran this in run mode, the memory usage of my app did not go above 8MB at all, while when it was in debug mode I got to the 25MB+ area.

Conclusion: Do not trust the GC and memory usage info in debug mode, especially if you have many short term threads running.